# Cookies via string from socket in python 3.6

Tags: python, sockets, cookies

Before all answers, want to explain, that I cant use library like "requests" only socket, so that's why I asked to help me.
I have a server on python which is generating HTTP response on any request.

```
def listenToClient(self, client):
        size = 2048
        while True:
            try:
                data = client.recv(size)
                if data:
                    self.cookie["session"] = random.randint(0, 1000000000)
                    expiration = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
                    self.cookie["session"]["domain"] = str(self.bind_host)
                    self.cookie["session"]["path"] = "/"
                    self.cookie["session"]["expires"] = expiration.strftime("%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S PST")
                    response_http = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nAccess-Control-Allow-Origin: *\nAccess-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Set-Cookie, *\n%s\nContent-Type: application/json\n\n%s\n" % (self.cookie.output(), json.dumps(response_json))
                    client.send(response_http.encode())
                    client.close()
                else:
                    raise error('Client disconnected')
            except:
                client.close()
                return False
```

Everything is working and it returning correctly response, like :

```
curl -X POST http://host:9999 -d '{"test":"test"}'
"{\"logged\":True}"
```

response which i printed :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Set-Cookie, *
Set-Cookie: session=344772952; Domain=0.0.0.0; expires=Fri, 19-Jan-2018 20:04:36 PST; Path=/
Content-Type: application/json

"{\"logged\":True}"
```

And in browser is getting correctly... but.. cookies is not setting in browser.... why?

Thanks